# I cant change the TextView on onTick() method

Tags: android, textview, countdowntimer

I cant dynamically change my textview whenever onTick method is called. But I dont think this method is being called, since it does not change my UI.

```
public class TimerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static TextView strTime;
private static CooldownTimer timer;

private final static long start = 60000;
private final static long interval = 1000;

//private static Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_timer,
                container, false);

        //handler = new Handler();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        strTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        timer = new CooldownTimer(getActivity(),start,interval);
        //timer.setMyActivity(getActivity());
    }

}

private static class CooldownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

    private Activity _context;
    private String current;

    private CooldownTimer(Activity c,long startTime, long interval){    
        super(startTime, interval);
        this._context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long currentTimeInSeconds = millisUntilFinished/1000;
        current = "" + currentTimeInSeconds;
        strTime.setText(current);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        _context.finish();
    }



}
```

}

Need Help on this. Thank you. Android beginner here.

**EDITED:**

I use here handler class to post from UI thread but still, no response.

```
public class TimerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static TextView strTime;
private static CooldownTimer timer;

private final static long start = 60000;
private final static long interval = 1000;

private static Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_timer,
                container, false);

        handler = new Handler();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        strTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
        timer = new CooldownTimer(getActivity(),start,interval);
        timer.start();
        //timer.setMyActivity(getActivity());
    }

}

public static class CooldownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

    private Activity _context;
    private String current;

    private CooldownTimer(Activity c,long startTime, long interval){    
        super(startTime, interval);
        this._context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long currentTimeInSeconds = millisUntilFinished/1000;
        current = "" + currentTimeInSeconds;
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
            public void run() {
                strTime.setText(current);   
            }   

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        _context.finish();
    }



}
}
```

Comment: And then just call `timer.start();` .

Comment: i call it in onStart();

Comment: It is giving you kind of an exception because you are modifying the UI thread from a background thread?

Comment: And how your `PlaceholderFragment ` attached to your `TimerActivity ` ? As I have doubt, what you are seen is your Activity's layout not a Fragment's layout, as your fragment is never initiated.

Comment: @user370305 ah ok, i get it. So do I need to create another xml file for the fragment? Or I could just place it on onCreate() of the Activity and remove Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I get it now, I reference both activity_timer.xml layout to Activity and the Fragment, which is why my fragment is never intantiated like @user370305 said.

here is the working code now:

```
public class TimerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static TextView strTime;
private static CooldownTimer timer;

private final static long start = 60000;
private final static long interval = 1000;

private static Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);

    handler = new Handler();

    strTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
    timer = new CooldownTimer(this,start,interval);
    timer.start();
}



public static class CooldownTimer extends CountDownTimer{

    private Activity _context;
    private String current;

    private CooldownTimer(Activity c,long startTime, long interval){    
        super(startTime, interval);
        this._context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long currentTimeInSeconds = millisUntilFinished/1000;
        current = "" + currentTimeInSeconds;
        handler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
            public void run() {
                strTime.setText(current);   
            }   

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        _context.finish();
    }



}
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You don't need `handler ` to update TextView . `onTick()` can update your TextView.